# radiogroup with button crashes

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use a radiogroup to determine which if statement to use the logcat states crash at the initialization of the radiogroup.

Below is the Java class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView BMR, TDEE;
EditText feet, inches, weight, age;
RadioGroup sex, activity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main); 

    feet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editFeet);
    inches = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editInches);
    weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editWeight);
    age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAge);
    BMR = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textBMR);
    TDEE = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTDEE);

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCalculate)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            int sexed = sex.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            int active = activity.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            if (sexed == R.id.radioMale) {
                int ft = Integer.parseInt(feet.getText().toString());
                int in = Integer.parseInt(inches.getText().toString());
                int pounds = Integer.parseInt(weight.getText().toString());
                double dAge = Double.parseDouble(age.getText().toString());

                 int convertedFeet = (ft * 12);
                 double cm = ((convertedFeet + in) * 2.54);
                 double kg = (pounds * 0.453592);
                 double bmr = ((66 + (13.7 * kg)+(5 * cm)- (6.8 * dAge)));

                 BMR.setText("BMR = " + bmr);
                    if (active == R.id.radioModerate) {
                        TDEE.setText("TDEE = " + (bmr * 1.55));
                    } if (active == R.id.radioVeryActive) {
                        TDEE.setText("TDEE = " + (bmr * 1.725));
                    } else {
                        TDEE.setText("TDEE = " + (bmr * 1.9));
                    }

            } else {
                int ft = Integer.parseInt(feet.getText().toString());
                int in = Integer.parseInt(inches.getText().toString());
                int pounds = Integer.parseInt(weight.getText().toString());
                double dAge = Double.parseDouble(age.getText().toString());

                 int convertedFeet = (ft * 12);
                 double cm = ((convertedFeet + in) * 2.54);
                 double kg = (pounds * 0.453592);
                 double bmr = ((655 + (9.6 * kg)+(1.8 * cm)- (4.7 * dAge)));

                 BMR.setText("BMR = " + bmr);
                    if (active == R.id.radioModerate) {
                        TDEE.setText("TDEE = " + (bmr * 1.55));
                    } if (active == R.id.radioVeryActive) {
                        TDEE.setText("TDEE = " + (bmr * 1.725));
                    } else {
                        TDEE.setText("TDEE = " + (bmr * 1.9));
                    }
            }

        }

    });

}
```

Here is my logcat:

```
06-12 14:16:39.030: I/Choreographer(859): Skipped 68 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. 
06-12 14:16:39.680: I/Choreographer(859): Skipped 68 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. 
06-12 14:16:39.880: D/gralloc_goldfish(859): Emulator without GPU emulation detected. 06-12 14:16:42.010: I/Choreographer(859): Skipped 44 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. 
06-12 14:16:55.720: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(859): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection 
06-12 14:17:03.430: D/AndroidRuntime(859): Shutting down VM 
06-12 14:17:03.430: W/dalvikvm(859): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a58ba8) 
06-12 14:17:03.490: E/AndroidRuntime(859): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
06-12 14:17:03.490: E/AndroidRuntime(859): Process: co.mytms.calorieintakecalculator, PID: 859 
06-12 14:17:03.490: E/AndroidRuntime(859): java.lang.NullPointerException 
06-12 14:17:03.490: E/AndroidRuntime(859):  at co.mytms.calorieintakecalculator.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:37) 
06-12 14:17:03.490: E/AndroidRuntime(859):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
06-12 14:17:03.490: E/AndroidRuntime(859):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
06-12 14:17:03.490: E/AndroidRuntime(859):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
06-12 14:17:03.490: E/AndroidRuntime(859):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
06-12 14:17:03.490: E/AndroidRuntime(859):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
06-12 14:17:03.490: E/AndroidRuntime(859):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
06-12 14:17:03.490: E/AndroidRuntime(859):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
06-12 14:17:03.490: E/AndroidRuntime(859):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
06-12 14:17:03.490: E/AndroidRuntime(859):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
06-12 14:17:03.490: E/AndroidRuntime(859):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
06-12 14:17:03.490: E/AndroidRuntime(859):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
06-12 14:17:07.810: I/Process(859): Sending signal. PID: 859 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Include your crash log

Comment: Can you show what is the line 37 on your `MainActivity`, there's an `NullPointerException` in this line.

Comment: because your `RadioGroup sex` has not been initialized. It is null and giving `NullPointerException` at `sex.getCheckedRadioButtonId();`

Comment: Thanks to Preeti Patwa that was my problem.